# How to clone a copy using ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-python-api, visual-studio-code

What I am trying to do: Take a layer from ArcGIS Enterprise, clone it as a temporary file, overwrite a file in SQL DB, delete temporary file.

What I have tried so far:

```py
def overwrite_existing_layer(source_layer_name, sql_database, layer_name):
    try:
  
        # Connect to the ArcGIS Portal
        gis = GIS('pro')
        portal_dstore = gis.datastore


        # Retrieve the feature layer you want to clone
        source_layer = gis.content.search(source_layer_name, item_type="Feature Layer")[0]
        
        # Create a temporary copy of the layer
        temporary_copy = source_layer.layers[0].query()
        
        # Save the temporary copy to overwrite the existing layer in the SQL database
Don't know how to do this using arcgis.gis. (tried a variety of things)

        print("Temporary copy overwritten in SQL database.")

        # Delete the temporary copy
        portal_dstore.delete_layers(temporary_copy)

        if not temporary_copy.exists:
            print("Temporary copy deleted.") 
        
        print('Finished running script')

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle any errors that occur during the process
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")`
```

Issue: I have not been able to find a way to save the copy to our SQL DB

Alternative option: Just clone the layer in portal and publish it back to portal (ultimate goal is to create view layers of clone which cannot be done on original)

Code I have tried for that:

```py
def overwrite_existing_layer(source_layer_name, layer_name):
    try:
        # Connect to the ArcGIS Portal
        gis = GIS('pro')
        portal_dstore = gis.datastore


        # Retrieve the feature layer you want to clone
        source_layer = gis.content.search(source_layer_name, item_type="Feature Layer")[0]
        
        # Create a temporary copy of the layer
        temporary_copy = ContentManager.clone_items(items=source_layer, folder=folder)


        print("Temporary copy overwritten in SQL database.")

        # Delete the temporary copy
        portal_dstore.delete_layers(temporary_copy)

        if not temporary_copy.exists:
            print("Temporary copy deleted.") 
        
        print('Finished running script')

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle any errors that occur during the process
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```

Issue: I have not been able to find a way to save the cloned layer to portal (this is probably confused on what is meant by folder. Is that just a folder I'd like it to be saved in within my enterprise portal?

Comment: For anyone that runs into a similar workflow, I have found a bit of a work around since I found no solution to copy and publish a layer... so instead I converted the original layer to a spatial dataframe using the .sdf  property. Then just republished a new layer from the data frame. Seems like there has to be a better way but that's what I have found using ESRI's documentation.